# During model constructions we always have cardinality restrictions on the models (ex: $|M| \leq |L| + \aleph_0$ or $|M| \geq |L| + \aleph_0$). Why?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I realize it has something to do with the number of formulas (with parameters potentially) but I can't articulate the idea exactly.

An obvious example:

In the statement of the Lowenheim Skolem Theorem, given a model $M$ and a set $A \subset M$ and a cardinality $\lambda \leq |M|$, we say we can find an elementary submodel $N$ of $M$, such that $A \subseteq M$, and $|N| \leq |A| + |L| + \aleph_0$, rather than just sayind $|N| = |A|$. What is the exact thing that we're accounting for when we add the extra $|L| + \aleph_0$?

More generally (and I would like to know the general "motivation" because I can get the indiviual cases like in the proof of the Lowenheim Skolem theorems) why we seem to require padding, and why the padding is (almost always) $|L| + \aleph_0$.

Comment: It's usually good practice to make your post self-contained, and not rely on the title for the actual question. It will also be helpful if you try to put more context into it, e.g. what kind of model constructions? Presumably ones coming from Löwenheim–Skolem theorems or compactness, or something else?

Comment: I gave an example (Lowenheim Skolem theorem) but this is one of the scenarios which you know happens always, but when put on the spot for a specific example, you blank. I realize that sounds like a dumb excuse, but I'm hoping that everyone here is familiar with how these cardinalities keep popping up. Sorry my question isn't more precise (my lack of understanding is probably why it's so imprecise). @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually due to some information or construction from formulas, and it's pretty easy to calculate that there are $|L|+\aleph_0$-many $L$-formulas.  I'll address the specific case of the Löwenheim–Skolem.  When taking an elementary submodel $N$ of a model $M$,

1. One reason for requiring $|N|\ge |L|$: our language could have a lot of constant symbols.

If our language $L$ consists just of $\kappa$-many constant symbols $c_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\kappa$ and $M$ thinks all of these constants are different, then any elementary submodel must also think all of these constants are different and must therefore have at least $\kappa=|L|$ many elements.

2. One reason for requiring $|N|\ge\aleph_0$: Infinitely many members of $M$ are definable.

If we think about $\mathbb{N}$, for example, any elementary submodel $N$ (in the finite language of $\{0,1,+,\cdot\}$) is going to need to contain $0$ and $1$.  We can from there define $2=1+1$, $3=2+1$, etc. so that these will need to be in $N$.  So it's not hard to see then that $N$ will need to be infinite (and in fact $\mathbb{N}$ itself).

Comment: Are there are only countably many definable elements no matter the language (and theory)? I'm inclined to think not, in which case I don't see why $|N| \geq \aleph_0$ is sufficient unless $L$ has very few symbols/is countable (I think).

Comment: @ArithmeticArthritis You can have many more definable elements if you have a large language (e.g. the language of a lot of constant symbols).  The point of the example is that *even if* you have a small language, you can have infinitely many.

Comment: Ah I understand. Although I suppose I'm asking about the case where the definable elements exceed $|L|$, i.e, is it not possible to have more definable elements than constant symbols?

Comment: Ah wait since you have $|L| + \aleph_0$ formulas you can have at most $|L| + \aleph_0$ definable elements, so everything works out if you require $|N| \geq |L| + \aleph_0$. Is that right?

Comment: @ArithmeticArthritis I think you get the idea: you can't have more definable elements than definitions (formulas).  As a comment on my answer though, of course, it's not just definable elements that are the issue.  Remember that the proof of the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem goes through closing under some skolem functions which just choose witnesses to existential statements.  The skolem functions have to output definable elements, but they also output a lot more (usually).  But the distinction isn't really important here when discussing size.  The point is they come from formulas.